# How to compute the derivative of the log-likelihood function of Gaussian?

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

$L=logp(y|x,\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}log|\Sigma|-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu)-\frac{n}{2}log(2\pi)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_\mu}=-(y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta_\mu}$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_k}=-\frac{1}{2}Tr(\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \theta_k})+\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \theta_k}\Sigma^{-1}(y-\mu)$

$M=logp(y_t|\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}log|C_t|-\frac{1}{2}(y_t-\mu_t)^TC_t^{-1}(y_t-\mu_t)-\frac{n}{2}log(2\pi)$

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial \theta_i}=-\frac{1}{2}Tr(C_t^{-1}\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial \theta_i})+\frac{1}{2}(y_t-\mu_t)^TC_t^{-1}\frac{\partial C_t}{\partial \theta_i}C_t^{-1}(y_t-\mu_t)+(\frac{\partial \mu_t}{\partial \theta_i})^TC_t^{-1}(y_t-u_t)$

This result is right? how to get this result?

Comment: The Matrix Cookbook http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!! But I want to know the detail of the process, because I can proof it by myself.

Comment: I gave you a useful reference. I leave you to do some work.

Comment: In the final expression you are missing several terms and some of the signs are wrong.  Reviewing the Chain Rule and Product Rules of differentiation will help.